# Play video on boot

Tags: android

I'm trying to start a project for android platform, which requires a video be played every time the tablet starts/boots. I have attempted by using third party automation app like AutomateIt but it is unsuccessful, I have tried using eclipse and android sdk, but I don't really know how to integrate video into app or run script that autoplay video on device boot. Does anyone can help me in this project? Many thanks

Comment: Check [here](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/boot-animation-manager-makes-changing-animations-a-breeze/) it will do the trick .

Answer (score 0):

You might need to look on Rom building (xda dev), custom roms or kernels are able to modify boot video . Like Cyanogen team does and other Kernel developers .

Answer (score 0):

you can use an intent-filter to trigger the start of your video:

> ```
>   <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
>                 <intent-filter>
>                     <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
>                 </intent-filter>
>   </receiver>
> ```

you will need the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
> ```

then the receiver can open your video activity

> ```
> import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.content.Intent;
>
> public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>           Intent start_i=new Intent(context,YourVideoPlaybackActivity.class);              
>           start_i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                       
>           context.startActivity(start_i);                                        
>         }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Is this a script? If this is, how can I use it?